# Changing colors of emails in Outlook 2007 - based on replied to status

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, colors

My manager would like to have any emails he hasn't replied to or forwarded within 24 hours of receipt to turn yellow and then red if he hasn't dealt with them within 48 hours.

I've gone through the various rule scenarios and cannot find a field I can use for "Replied" or "Forwarded" ...

I've looked at flagging all incoming emails for action "Today" and that turns all untouched emails red if they go past Close of Business, but it also adds all of his emails to his task list - which made the top of his head explode, so I had to remove that rule.

Any suggestions?  I'm at the limit of my limited expertise with Outlook Rules.  I'm willing to look at coding something if someone has VERY specific code samples I can cut, paste and modify.

Comment: you will probably need to use third party APIs like this: http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Rules and Alerts as you can't do conditional formatting. You can do this via  .NET and have that run via Scheduled tasks but for actual code you would be better going to Stack Overflow.

Or, do it via a macro ([how to create a macro)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/synergist/adding-a-vba-macro-to-outlook) and have the macro [scheduled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226311/schedule-outlook-2003-macro). Again, you should head to Stack Overflow for actual code but do some research first as you'll probably find it is achievable.

General [color changing guide](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/site/silentsignin?returnUrl=https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/vba-how-to-change-font-color-etc-in-an-email/67d1201f-806b-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) by VBA